# Does aws has alternative nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cloud

I tried to find alternative of nginx on aws, and found only route 53. Is it the same service or no?
Does aws has alternative nginx?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NGINX is a web server which can also be used as a reverse proxy, load balancer and HTTP cache ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)). It is software that runs on an operating system (eg Linux, Windows).

There is no equivalent provided by AWS. You can run NGINX on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The closest equivalents on AWS would be:

- Using **Amazon S3** to serve static web content
- Using **Elastic Load Balancer** to distribute traffic to multiple Amazon EC2 instances
- Using **Amazon CloudFront** to cache content in multiple geographic locations

**Amazon Route 53** is a DNS service for resolving domain names, which is not base NGINX functionality (although NGINX can handle virtual hosts, which overlaps a bit with DNS).

Comment: You can't really create custom urls with those options.  E.g. in nginx I map /contact-us/ to a completely different url, but none of the above services have to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda @ Edge sitting in front of a Cloudfront distribution can replace many of the functionalities of Nginx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).